# Log in screen background different from desktop

Tags: login-screen, desktop-background

Since Ubuntu 13.04, in my laptop, when I choose an image as desktop background from my pictures folder, the login screen remains as the default purple image. 
To solve that I had to add the image I wanted to /usr/share/backgrounds.

Later on, I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and the same thing happened. 
But then, one day I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in another computer, and I realized that when I chose an image from the pictures folder as desktop background, the image appeared in the login screen.
So how is this possible?
Is it because I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 in my laptop, and the one in the other computer was a fresh installation of 13.10?
And, what can I do to fix this?

Best regards,

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ubuntu tweak If you haven't installed yet.

open it go to tweaks tab then Login settings and there you can choose your login wallpaper.

[image]

to install ubuntu tweak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But the mystery still remains...

Comment: Welcome. Its better to mark as answer if it helps. The mystery is the update the old files and configuartions still the same of 13.04 after update